# Is it possible to have a GUI in world space in Unity3D game?

Tags: unity, 3d

I'm trying to make a tank shooter game for learning purpose and I want to have it viewed in first person, is there a way to make it so that the GUI seems projected onto the interior of the tank chamber so that I can look around without the GUI following the camera along with having the perspective change effects (i.e. the edge of the GUI further away from the camera appears smaller than the edge closer to the center of the camera)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, You can do this in very simple way by creating 3d Text/TextMesh for the text and Quads for images.

Comment: Is this can be done in Unity5 too?

Comment: Yes. its almost same for all version of unity.

Comment: Thanks. I am able to make it work on Unity4, and its working on device. i will try with Unity5.

Comment: Can you tell us more about "perspective related issues" ? Unity UI features are powerfull, so why not using those and doing it all by hand ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible and here is the [documentation](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HOWTO-UIWorldSpace.html)